# Combining Two 'if-statement' .second is depend on the first

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

second 'If' can come only after the first statement so there will not be run time error- due to the fact that "el_rule"  can be sometimes nothing.. 
so i can't put both in same statement with **AND**.
but after both 'if statement' i want same lines of code will run if one of the if statement will not happens(else)... is my only option is too just write it twice?
like on following code? thanks for any help!

```
If el_rule.Length > 0 Then
                    If LCase(ActiveCell.Offset(0, el_rule.Item(0).Attributes.getNamedItem("column_number").Text).Value) = LCase(el_rule.Item(0).Attributes.getNamedItem("value").Text) Then
                     Set el = xDoc.SelectNodes("/simulator")

                 Else
                   Set el =.......   -code first time
               End If
else
                   Set el =.......    -code second time
               End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a helper `Boolean` variable

```
Dim doIt As Boolean

If el_rule.Length > 0 Then doIt = LCase(ActiveCell.Offset(0, el_rule.item(0).Attributes.getNamedItem("column_number").Text).Value) = LCase(el_rule.item(0).Attributes.getNamedItem("value").Text)
If doIt Then
    Set el = xDoc.SelectNodes("/simulator")    
Else
    Set el =.......   -code only time
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow (since I don't know what `el_rule` is), but VBA doesn't have short-circuiting of its Boolean operators such as `And`. As a consequence, nested `If` statements are more common in VBA than in other languages. If `el_rule` is sometimes nothing then you would need to have code like:

```
If Not el_rule Is Nothing Then
    If el_rule.Length > 0 Then 
       'Code in which el_rule is something And with Length > 0
    End If
Else
    'code to handle the case when el_rule is nothing
End If
```

As an alternative, if it is genuinely an exceptional situation for `el_rule` to be nothing, you could simply write code that assumes it isn't and use error handling to catch the times when it is.

Comment: @David This is a template only. any needed end if for the inner if is implicit in the ellipsis in the comment `'...`

Comment: @David I made the template a bit more explicit.

Comment: @David - Actually, the original `If` statement would not have required two `End If` statements because the inner `If` was a single-line `If`.  But I like the later template better because I find single-line `If` statements confusing when I read code.